# When does the open beta phase begin?

Tags: support

I want to alert someone who knows way more than I do to this site, letting him know when he could begin to participate.

Other than the general guide that private betas last 1-2 weeks, is the date someone can join the open beta known?

Thanks,

Roger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The private beta generally lasts 1-2 weeks. The sites (generally) go public on either Tuesday or Wednesday evening. But our final evaluations are not completed until just before a decision is made (i.e. the public launch date is TBD).

Having said that, you can invite your colleagues to join the private beta at any time. Look to the front page:

[image]

Comment: Is this scorecard for "passing" private beta? or is this for public beta? http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51674?phase=beta&users=reputation#tab-top

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't noticed the invite at all. I've used this to invite this maven -- I hope he has time to accept it.

Comment: @DmitryKachaev That "scorecard" (for lack of a better word) generally has very little effect on private beta evaluations. It's more about looking at the level of engagement, expertise, scope, and what's on that front page in preparation of opening day — **[Asking the first questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/)**

Comment: As we've been more than a week ... does that mean this Tuesday we should expect it to open up?

Answer (score 4):

On Tuesday, May 21, this site transitioned from private beta to public beta. This was the thirteenth day since the site began.

Information about the site (how many questions are asked per day, how many users are there, how many questions get answered, etc.) and its top users can be found at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51674/open-data), the Stack Exchange Network staging zone.